# Nodejs / javaScript manipulate CSV files

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Hi I've two CSV files.

1. Spas.csv
2. Customers.csv

**Spas.csv**

```
id  | name
...........................
5   | Wasana spa
...........................
7   | Hot spring spa
...........................
8   | Colombo spa
...........................
10  | Sanhida spa
...........................
12  | Waruna spa
...........................
```

**Customers.csv**

```
id  | name  | spaId
........................
1   |Hiran  |5
........................
2   |Hirushi|5
........................
3   |Mishani|8
........................
4   |Chamod |12
```

These two CSV files exported from a `MYSQL DB`.
What I want is change `spaId` of the `Customers.csv` file like this.

```
id  | name  | spaId
........................
1   |Hiran  |1
........................
2   |Hirushi|1
........................
3   |Mishani|3
........................
4   |Chamod |5
```

These new spaId comes from the line number of the **Spas.csv** file.
Example :- id 5 was at the line number 1, so number 5 is replaced with the number 1.

How do I achieve this in nodejs / javaScript. What I've done upto now is this.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var csv = require('fast-csv');

fs.createReadStream('spas.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data',function(data){
        console.log('DATA',data)
    })
    .on('end',function(data){
        console.log("FIN",data)
    })
```

Basically this will console log the each line as a array and I don't know how to write to the CSV same time.

Comment: This is not a csv file

Comment: @JKK I update my question and put the code I've already.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
const fs = require("fs");

const csv = require("fast-csv");

async function getSpasIdMap(filePath){

   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

     let map = {};

     let count = 0;

     let stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

     let csvStream = csv({ headers:true })
     .on("data", function(data){
         map[data.id] = ++count;
     })
     .on("error", (e) => {
         reject(e);
     })
     .on("end", function(){
         resolve(map);
     });

     stream.pipe(csvStream);
 })
}

async function computeAndWriteCustomerData(spasSource, customerSource, dest){

  let spasMap = await getSpasIdMap(spasSource);

  let customerStream = fs.createReadStream(customerSource);

  let csvCustomerStream = csv({headers:true})
  .transform(function(row) {
      return `${row.name},${spasMap[row.spaId]}\n`;
  });

  let writableStream = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  customerStream.pipe(csvCustomerStream);
  csvCustomerStream.pipe(writableStream);
}

async function main() {
    await computeAndWriteCustomerData("spas.csv", "customer.csv", "my.csv");
}

main();
```